# angular ngx-datatable serverside filtering

Tags: angular, filter, datatable

I wanna do the ngx-datatable filtering percolumn on serverside anybody can help me?
I have two input field and I want the table display the result of my search with that inputs
I've did something like this :
[example](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/)
but insted of mat-table I'm using a ngx-data-table and I dont know how to connect the dataSource to my ngx-table

Comment: What exactly do you need help in? Have you written the APIs on your backend, required for filtering?

Comment: I've did something like this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/   but insted of mat-table I'm using a ngx-data-table and I dont know how to connect the dataSource to my ngx-table